# Binance Websocket for futures

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I can't make the websocket for COIN-M on Binance returns any data.
I managed to get it to work with the SPOT endpoint, but in the Futures it is a null response.

```
import websocket
import _thread
import time
import json

WEBSOCKET_URL_FUTURES = "wss://dstream.binance.com/ws"
WEBSOCKET_URL_SPOT = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws"

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(f'ONMESSAGE######: {message}')
    with open ('./data.json', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{message}\n')

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(f'ONERROR####: {error}')

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    print("### opened ###")
    subscribe_message = {
        "method": "SUBSCRIBE",
        "params":
        [
         "ethusd_perpetual@aggTrade"
         ],
         "id": 1
         }
    list_message = {
        "method": "LIST_SUBSCRIPTIONS",
        "id": 3

    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_message))
    ws.send(json.dumps(list_message))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(WEBSOCKET_URL_SPOT,
                              on_open=on_open,
                              on_message=on_message,
                              on_error=on_error,
                              on_close=on_close)

    ws.run_forever()
```

I'm trying differents parameters in the SUSBCRIBE method but neither of them returns anything.
Also, I can't find any list with all the possible symbol pairs that could be used.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a typo in your stream URL.

The code uses `wss://dstream...`, while this should be `wss://fstream...`